# how to set xaml mapcontrol mapicon always visible

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm fairly new to programming in XAML and I'm making a test application on windows phone 8.1 emulator with a MapControl.

I wanted to add a MapIcon to my map but the icon doesn't appear when the map is zoomed out. I've searched the internet and couldn't find anything regarding my problem.

I want my zoomlevel 12 and show the mapicon on that zoomlevel.

```
namespace TEST.APPLICATION
{
public partial class MapView : Page
{
    Geolocator geo = null;
    public MapView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    }
    void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            Frame.GoBack();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        map.Center = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
           {
              Latitude = 51.5856935784736,
              Longitude = 4.79448171225132
           });
        map.ZoomLevel = 12;

        displaySightings();
    }

    private void displaySightings()
    {
        MapIcon sighting1 = new MapIcon();
        sighting1.Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
        {
            Latitude = 51.5940,
            Longitude = 4.7795
        });
        //sighting1.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0);
        sighting1.Title = "VVV";
        map.MapElements.Add(sighting1);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make the MapIcon always visible?

Answer (score 2):

[The MapIcon is not guaranteed to be shown. It may be hidden when it obscures other elements or labels on the map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn792121.aspx).

For some stupid reason, Microsoft thought that labels and other map elements should outrank map icons when rendering the display.  So, if you're making an app displaying the locations of all the nearby Starbucks, the name of the high school *across the street from the Starbucks* is more important than the pushpin, according to them.

You'll need to render the pushpins using XAML instead.

Comment: What do you mean with 'You'll need to render the pushpins using XAML instead.'?

Comment: Second half of the page linked above, specifically "Display a XAML shape (in this example, an ellipse) on the map" if you want to do it in code.

Comment: Adding a fence doesn't seem to work for me. I tried to add the ellipse to my map. The ellipse part of the example, but  it gives the error: ' Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl.SetLocation(Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject, Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geopoint)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead